MyBatis3 There is no setter for property named '1' in 'class java.lang.String'
I have a problem, I need to query all the data by the table name, but recently found a problem, I reported an error when querying a customer table.

Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property '1' of 'class java.lang.String' with value '0' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named '1' in 'class java.lang.String'
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:156)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:142)
at com.levin.fastgen.dao.TestDAO.sessionSelect(TestDAO.java:303)
at com.levin.fastgen.dao.TestDAO.queryDataByTableName(TestDAO.java:295)
at com.levin.fastgen.FastGen.run(FastGen.java:189)
at com.levin.fastgen.FastGen.main(FastGen.java:116)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property '1' of 'class java.lang.String' with value '0' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named '1' in 'class java.lang.String'
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BeanWrapper.setBeanProperty(BeanWrapper.java:181)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BeanWrapper.set(BeanWrapper.java:61)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.setValue(MetaObject.java:119)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.BaseWrapper.setChildValue(BaseWrapper.java:133)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.MapWrapper.set(MapWrapper.java:53)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.setValue(MetaObject.java:119)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyAutomaticMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:592)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:416)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:366)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:337)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:310)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:202)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:66)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:65)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:336)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:158)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:110)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:90)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:154)
... 6 more

I have arranged a minimal reproduction collection, please help to have a look
mybatis version: 3.5.17
mysql version: 5.6 (Nothing to do with the database)
CREATE TABLE `test_1` (
`账单号` varchar(255) COMMENT 'null',
`账单号.1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'null'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test_1` VALUES ('0','0');

It looks like the BeanWrapper function is the cause.I hope he can work properly
I analyzed the possible problems and here they are

The exception is thrown from a SELECT statement, not INSERT. If you enable TRACE level logging, it will print the SQL and parameters. Please add 1) the log output, 2) the mapper statement definition (including the XML tag) and 3) related class definitions if there is any. And, please use text instead of images (markdown supports syntax coloring. see the help). Alternatively, if you could share a small repro project like these, it may save both of our time.

@ave ok repro project these Can you follow up on this for me? thanks –

That is basically the same problem as this question. Please see my answer there for the solution.
